# Specific questions about Blockchain

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

I have familiarized with the blockchain technology for some time through internet research and tutorials, but, as blockchain often appears as a business topic, I could not find good answers to some technical questions. I hope, some of you could help me:

1. The concept of blockchain says that all transaction data is stored on every node (e.g. computer) of the network. Isn’t that a huge and continuously growing amount of data every single participant should store? (If the answer is that just certain nodes have to save the whole history, wouldn’t this be in contrast to the idea of decentralization?)
2. What is the purpose for the very complex hashing procedure of Bitcoin? As far as I understand it, hashing is needed for the immutability of the chain, but why does it have to be so time-consuming as it is? On the other hand hashing is often considered as a „signature“ of the miner; what does that mean? Doesn’t signature usually mean something like a private key?
3. As blockchain is of course not bitcoin, is this complex hashing procedure also needed for other use cases (like supply chain applications…) or can it be replace by simpler hashes?
4. To protect privacy the participants of a blockchain are mostly hashed as well, which is often listed as a great advantage of the technology. In more exclusive blockchains than the bitcoin, isn’t it very simple to conclude some players through their behavior. I mean, if a very big party participates in the blockchain, it is well detectable by e.g. the frequency or volume of deals.
5. If a miner has hashed and added a block, do all the other miners instantly reject the block they currently try to create?
6. How does blockchain synchronize the transactions? In distributed systems it is always a big deal to clarify which action happened first. Some of the blockchain literature sources say that all transactions of a blockchain are first stored in a pool before adding to a block. This would be bad in e.g. auction-like deals.
7. Some sources state that a chain is considered correct when the majority (51%) of the nodes contains it. How does it work/ when is this checked? On the homepage https://medium.com/coinmonks/what-is-a-51-attack-or-double-spend-attack-aa108db63474 the 51% refer to the computational capacities and not the number of nodes and in the context of an attack…

Thank you very much in advance! I will appreciate your answers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: "Majority" does not mean "51%."  It means "more than 50%."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Yes, every node has to store the entire history. The hope is that storage tech improvements outpace the growth of the blockchain.
2. Hashing is used in a lot of different ways in blockchains. The first use you mention is the proof of work, and the very fact that it's extremely hard makes blockchains work. It's so hard that you would need impossible amounts of computing power for one person to hold in order to rewrite the blockchain in your favor. The other use of hashing is to provide anonymous identity using public and private keys.
3. Yes, no. But there are other forms of proof which do not rely on hashing.
4. Yes, and this is why bitcoin tumbling is a thing - to try to hide any sort of trail to you.
5. Yes
6. The block includes a timestamp which gets hashed as well and stored in the blockchain as proof. But before transactions are part of a block, it's unclear what happened first. This is why you should always wait for you transactions to be mined before considering them final.
7. This goes back to point 2. When one individual has the power of over 51% of the network, they are able to produce correct hashes at a faster rate than the rest of the network and can thus out compete it in producing a valid blockchain. This effectively means the individual has the power to write whatever they want into the blocks as well as rewrite previous history